# Problem with GetFeatureInfo request on INSPIRE cadastre using Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, wms, getfeatureinfo

Using Leaflet with the https://github.com/heigeo/leaflet.wms library, I have problems with GetFeatureInfo on the WMS INSPIRE cadastre. However the normal WMS works without problems. In the case of INSPIRE, there is a significant displacement and it does not correspond to the selected point.

I have made different CRS settings but I have not been able to get it to work correctly. I leave the inclusion code of the two services.

Has anyone had this problem?

```
  L.WMS.source("https://ovc.catastro.meh.es/cartografia/INSPIRE/spadgcwms.aspx?", {
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
});
source.getLayer("CP.CADASTRALPARCEL").addTo(map);

L.WMS.source("http://ovc.catastro.meh.es/Cartografia/WMS/ServidorWMS.aspx?", {
    opacity: 0.1,
});
source.getLayer("PARCELA").addTo(map);
```

Comment: I had a look in QGIS, using the identity tool to identify a plot labelled 14, by both WMS layers `CP.CADASTRALPARCEL` and `PARCELA`. I agree I get a different plot id returned by both `4621314VK3742B` and `46213Z9VK3742B`.  I conclude the issue is with the data, not an issue with the requests made.  You should contact the service providers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone encounters this problem. For this service, Cadastro uses I, J instead of X, Y in queries.

Comment: Version 1.3.0 of the the WMS specification says you must use i,j whilst for version 1.1.1 you must use x,y to identify the pixel of interest.